# Building sequence in datalog

Tags: datalog

I'm using a version of datalog with negation. I'm trying to write a program that assigns increasing sequence numbers of each row in a relation. Example:

Given some EDB

`items("a", "b")
items("a", "c")
items("b", "b")`

I'd like to be able to generate the following IDB that assigns a sequence value to each row in `items`:

`items_with_seq("a", "b", 0)
items_with_seq("a", "c", 1)
items_with_seq("b", "b", 2)`

Comment: As @winter answered, a sequence number dependent on the sequence of definition is conceptually not possible. However if there is a total order on the facts (e.g. if you can build a list of tuples with unique order), you can derive sequence numbers from this list.

Answer (score 0):

The query evaluation in Datalog is based on [first-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Free_and_bound_variables), for this reason, it has some limitations. It is not possible to characterize countability or uncountability in a first-order language.

Check [Countability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set).

Answer (score 0):

In [Souffle](https://souffle-lang.github.io/) datalog you could use the [choice construct](https://souffle-lang.github.io/choice):

```
.decl items(x:symbol, y:symbol)
items("a","b").
items("a","c").
items("b","b").

// choice-domain is key here:
// - couples of (x,y) must be unique
// - seq must be unique
.decl items_with_seq(x:symbol, y:symbol, seq:number) choice-domain (x,y),seq
.output items_with_seq()

.decl items_size(n:number)
items_size(n) :- 
  n = count: {items(_,_)}.

items_with_seq(x,y,seq) :- 
  items(x,y),
  items_size(n),
  seq = range(0,n).
```

Outputs:

```
---------------
items_with_seq
x       y       seq
===============
a       b       0
a       c       1
b       b       2
===============
```

Alternatively if you only need unique identifiers instead of sequence numbers:

```
items("a","b").
items("a","c").
items("b","b").

.decl items_with_seq(x:symbol, y:symbol, seq:number) choice-domain (x,y)
.output items_with_seq()

items_with_seq(x,y,autoinc()) :-
    items(x,y).
```